# No Bean Spring JMS with IBM MQ

Tags: ibm-mq, spring-jms

Is it possible to get messages from an IBM MQ (synchronously  or asynchronously) using Spring JMS alone - without using any Bean?

I am looking for a design where I can get messages from an MQ (IBM in this case) using Spring alone - process the message and pass it on.

Kindly suggest if it is possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a `JmsTemplate` (synchronous) or `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` (asynchronous) directly, without declaring them as beans; be sure to call `afterPropertiesSet()` after setting the properties and before `start()` ing the container, though.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Going with JmsTemplate.